# Function for selecting next Day If the last day is weekend

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime, weekend

I am trying to create a function that checks the range of date. If the last date is an weekend it will select the next day. Suppose, Today is 1 March 2016. If someone add 5 with it, it will make the result 7 March 2016. Because 6 March is Weekend. I have written this code. But it is not working and I cannot find where is the problem. The code is as below:

```
<?php
$date = "2016-02-29";
$numOfDays = 8;
$futureDate = strtolower(date("l",strtotime($date." +".$numOfDays."days")));
$weekend1= "friday";
$weekend2= "saturday";

        if($futureDate != $$w1 || $futureDate != $w2){
            $finalDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($futureDate));
        }
        else{$finalDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($futureDate ."+1 day"));}

        echo $finalDate;
?>
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `$w1` rather than `$$w1`

Comment: Yup..I meant $w1. Check the code. The name of the variables are changed.

Comment: @MuminurRahman check out my code. Its as per your code modified it further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
  <?php
$date = "2016-02-29";
$numOfDays = 11;
$futureDate = strtolower(date("l",strtotime($date ."+".$numOfDays."days")));
$futureDate1 = strtolower(date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date ."+".$numOfDays."days")));
$weekend1= "friday";
$weekend2= "saturday";

if($futureDate == $weekend1){
      $finalDate1 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($futureDate1 ."+2 days"));
}
if ($futureDate == $weekend2){
      $finalDate1 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($futureDate1 ."+1 days"));
}

echo $finalDate1;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This is not working properly. It does not select the next day if the day is a weekend.

Comment: @MuminurRahman you consider friday and saturday as week end or saturday and sunday? Above code will give you 2016-03-13 because 11 and 12 are friday and saturday

Comment: @MuminurRahman my latest code? Check it on http://www.writephponline.com/ its showing 2016-03-13

Comment: Yeah...It is working. Thanks. :) I think, there is a problem in my IDE.

Comment: @MuminurRahman welcome :) request you to please accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

March 6th, 2016 is a Sunday, but you're checking for Friday and Saturday, you need to check for Saturday and Sunday instead, for the weekend. Also, your variable names need to match, and for Saturday you'll need to add two days to get the next weekday.

```
<?php
$date = "2016-02-29";
$numOfDays = 8;
$day = 86400;//one day is 86400 seconds
$time = strtotime($futureDate + $numOfDays * $day);//converts $futureDate to a UNIX timestamp
$futureDate = strtolower(date("l", $time));
$saturday = "saturday";
$sunday = "sunday";
if($futureDate == $saturday){
    $finalDate = date("Y-m-d", $time + 2 * $day);
}
else if($futureDate == $sunday){
    $finalDate = date("Y-m-d", $time + $day);
}
else{
    $finalDate = date("Y-m-d", $time);
}
echo($finalDate);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works fine as I am trying to make. But the question is: When  I put bigger number than 6 it does not work and add one day. Could you please explain it?

Comment: Yeah, the `strtotime()` function will convert a date string to a unix timestamp (the amount of time, in seconds, since January 1, 1970). The `strtotime()` function cannot do arithmetic and doesn't know how to interpret " + 8 days", so the date must be converted to a timestamp, then we can add the amount of time (in seconds) that we want for the future date.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable explanation... :)

Answer (score 0):

@Fakhruddin Ujjainwala
I have changed in your code and it works now perfect. Thanks. the code is now as below:

```
<?php
$date = "2016-02-29";
$numOfDays = 4;
$futureDate = strtolower(date("l",strtotime($date ."+".$numOfDays."days")));
$futureDate1 = strtolower(date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date ."+".$numOfDays."days")));
$weekend1= "friday";
$weekend2= "saturday";

if($futureDate == $weekend1){
      $finalDate1 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($futureDate1 ."+2 days"));
}
else if ($futureDate == $weekend2){
      $finalDate1 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($futureDate1 ."+1 days"));
}
else{
    $finalDate1 = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($futureDate1));
}

echo $finalDate1;
?>
```